# Detailed working of JK flip flop?

Tags: flipflop

[image]

Let’s put J=1, K=0, CLK=1; The output of the circuit will be Q=1 & Q(-)=0; But when the feedback goes back to input (Q is attached to K and Q(-) is attached to J). Hence J input will be (0.1.1) & K input will be (1.0.1). Hence output from the first stage Nand gates are 1 & 1. So how it is stable. So feedback is changing the operation of the J=1,K=0,clk=1 operation. Please explain how feedback is affecting the output.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is.

Comment: To diagnose feedback paths you need to disconnect the feedback path and consider the operation open loop, also realize there is a delay in a real world flipflop

Answer (score 1):

How is this inconsistent?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIWY1G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This answer my question. I was not considering the feedback from Nand RS flip-flop. Foolishness on my part. Thanks Andrew.